# Returning a first element from an improper list in Erlang

Tags: list, erlang, head, tail

So I've been trying to implement this function in my module and so far I got this:

EXAMPLE 1.

```
[2,[3,[4,[5,[6,[7,[8,[]]]]]]]]
```

I am trying to figure out how I can make it look like a proper list, ie:

EXAMPLE 2.

```
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8].
```

I know I have to play with Heads and Tails but I am miserably failing at understanding it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I want to know what am I supposed to do next aka what would be the second line to solve my problem.

Comment: You wrote that you were having difficulty understanding what is needed, so I wrote a manual solution -- but Odobenus Rosmarus' answer is the correct way since this is indeed already a proper list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually in the example 1 you show proper list. List that just consists of 2 elements - number and another list.

Improper list is different thing - for instance [1|2].

You can turn example 1 into example 2 by lists:flatten.

```
1> M = [2,[3,[4,[5,[6,[7,[8,[]]]]]]]].
[2,[3,[4,[5,[6,[7,[8,[]]]]]]]]
2> lists:flatten(M).
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Answer (score 3):

The root of the problem is how you have built your list. What you have here:

```
[2,[3,[4,[5,[6,[7,[8,[]]]]]]]]
```

is not one list but nested lists each of two elements. When you do `[Element,List]` this does **NOT** prepend `Element` to `List` but builds a new list with `Element` as the first element and `List` as the second element. Note that each list **is** a proper list but you have not built one list but nested lists.

To prepend `Element` to `List` you use the syntax `[Element | List]`. So:

```
[2|[3|[4|[5|[6|[7|[8|[]]]]]]]]
```

which builds the list `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`.

So `[Element | List]` and `[Element,List]` are two very different things, the first prepends an element to the beginning of a list while the second builds a new list of two elements. There is no direct way of appending an element to a list without rebuilding the list.

Answer (score 1):

Not as obvious as it looks at first, but this is a manual way of doing what lists:flatten/1 does (in this particular case, its more interesting otherwise):

```
proper(L) -> proper([], L).

proper(A, [H|[T]]) -> proper([H|A], T);
proper(A, []) -> lists:reverse(A).
```